# Using diff in Hebrew

Tags: diff, hebrew

I am new to diff. I have used it in the past. But I want to know, can one use diff to track differences between two files in Hebrew? I am wanting to compare Biblical Hebrew files that have vowel points and accents.

Comment: What happens when you try to compare the differences in Hebrew?

Comment: Just for clarification, what constitutes a difference?  If the letters are the same, but the vowels different, do you consider them the same words or different?

Comment: It would seem that the process will need to read the files right to left in order to do a valid comparison.

Comment: My apologies. I haven't tried to use diff yet on Hebrew in Java. As I recall, however, when I used a tool like Notepad, it displayed the letters left-to-right instead of right-to-left. 

If the vowels are different, then the word is different.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of any "diff" (file comparison) tool that is capable of producing reasonable output when run on Biblical Hebrew.

What I would advise is to first transform the Biblical Hebrew into a representation that can be "diffed" and then run a "diff" program on it. This is what I have done when I have needed to do such a "diff."

For instance I transform the 1st 3 words of Genesis,

בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים

Into the following (one word per bulleted list item)

- v,·,:,r,‥,α,$,·sh,i,[ti],y,τ
- v,·,a,r,a,⅃,α
- α,:∵,l,o,h,i,⅄,y,m.

My [diffable-pointed-hebrew](https://github.com/bdenckla/diffable-pointed-hebrew) GitHub repo contains a Python program that performs such a transformation. It outputs a JSON file containing:

- first, a table of metadata describing the transformation
- then, a list of lines, where lines are lists of words, where words are strings that were separated by spaces in the input file.

See sample-input.txt & sample-output.json in that repo.